# Optimized integer and string input in C++

Tags: c++, input

In this code I am trying to input one number and a string `t` times but it is giving a run-time error during second iteration.

Input:

```
2
2 6
10 11
```

Runtime error   time: 0 memory: 3436 signal:11

```
  2 6 6
```

Please help me to remove this error.
I have used optimized input for both integer and string input.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


inline int getint(){
    int num=0;
    char c=getchar_unlocked();
    while(!(c>='0' && c<='9'))
        c=getchar_unlocked();

    while(c>='0' && c<='9'){
        num=(num<<3)+(num<<1)+(c-'0');
        c=getchar_unlocked();
    }
    return num;
}

inline void read_string(char *str){
    char c = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while(!(c>='0' && c<='9'))
        c=getchar_unlocked();

    while (c != '\n'){
        str[i] = c;
        c = getchar_unlocked();
        i = i + 1;
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
}

int main() {
    int t,A,i,j;
    char b[255];
    scanf("%d",&t);

    while(t--){
        A = getint();
        cout<<A<<" ";
        read_string(b);
        string B(b);
        cout<<b<<" "<<B<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? At what line exactly does it break? What is the input triggering the error? Do you need both input types? Is there anything you have tried so far?

Comment: What exactly do you want to read from the input?

Comment: @Ulrich Yes, error is coming during read_string in second iteration but its working in the first iteration. I need both input types its a part of a problem. I tried to use scanf for int but situation remains the same, but everything works fine if i use scanf for string input

Comment: @user2548635 I want to read an integer and a string separated by a space in each iteration and for each iteration values are in a different line

Comment: One thing that's pretty obvious is that you don't have any safeguard that will keep you from writing beyond the allocated buffer. BTW: What's the reason for the 255? Why not 312? Or 187? Just that it's a power of two or one less isn't going to make your program correct. This is just something to think about though, the exact buffer size isn't your problem here.

Comment: input string can't be more than 250 characters that's why there is 255.

Comment: How do you get that value? And how do you get from 250 to 255?

Comment: that's just for safety.